# Find number of one-one functions from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a set $X$, let $P(X)$ denote the power set of $X$. Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5\}$, I need to find the number of one-one functions from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$.

$P(A)=2^3=8$, $P(B)=2^2=4$.

Should it be zero as the number of elements in set $P(B)$ is less than set $P(A)$ and so not possible that there will be a unique mapping from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In the last line, I suppose you want to replace "$A$" and "$B$" with "$P(A)$" and "$P(B)$".

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I have corrected. Thanks!